# Does Docusign keeps a copy of sending document when we make a API call - eSignRestAPI?

Tags: security, docusignapi

Does Docusign keeps a copy of sending document when we make a API call CreatEnvelope using eSignRestAPI? if yes than is there any way to delete that document due to security reasons

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please upvote all useful answers (including those for questions by others. PLEASE check the best answer to your own question and upvote all useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, all of the documents in a DocuSign envelope (transaction) are stored by DocuSign. They are very well encrypted and protected. DocuSign can supply additional details as part of a customer's security audit of DocuSign.

You can certainly have DocuSign purge the data:

- set up an [automatic purge schedule](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-purge-envelopes)
- use the web tool to initiate a purge
- you can use the [api](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/update#purging-documents-from-docusign) to purge the documents from a specific envelope.

You can also sign up for the DocuSign key manager. It is a server on your premises that holds the encryption keys for the documents in the envelopes you send. That way you can immediate make the contents of the envelopes unreadable by DocuSign by turning off your key manager server.

[Press release](https://www.docusign.co.uk/press-releases/new-docusign-security-appliance-delivers-greater-flexibility-to-enhance-security-and). For more information, ask your DocuSign contact about the "DocuSign Security Appliance"

### Added

To purge envelope documents immediately after signing, use the Connect webhook system to be notified when an envelope has been completed. Then use the API to initiate the purge operation. You probably want to download the signed documents before purging them.

Comment: Thanks Larry for your quick response. I want to delete the signed document from DocuSign as soon as recipient click on finish button in DocuSign. Can you suggest any API spicific for purge operation which will remove envelope once document is signed.for the last paragraph solution is there any documentation available?

Comment: @see my updated answer. Please check and upvote my answer if it is help.